# If new (order preserving) dictionary is so amazing, should the list object be eschewed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

### Summary

The new `dict` is so amazing, I would anticipate that people are just going to start using them- with the indexes as the keys- for everything. Should they? If not, why not?

### Details

I have been following the very exciting (to me, anyway) developments/changes to the python dictionary implementation. In summary: the implementation has been changed such that the order of dictionaries is now preserved, AND they are now much more compact/memory efficient:

https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/773978885092323328?lang=en

Furthermore: it looks as if permanent order-preservation, though not currently guaranteed, is inevitable.

My question is: given that the memory efficiency has been so greatly improved, order is preserved, AND you get much faster item deletion/insertion with a `dict`, is there any good reason to NOT to use a dictionary for ANY sequence of items, using the indexes as keys?

To expand on the question: would it ever make sense to change the underlying sequence (`list` and `tuple`) implementation to use the same techniques as the order-preserving `dict` (again: using the indexes as the keys/hashes)?

The answer to this question may be very obvious to someone who has taken a few computer science courses. I'm just a doofus civil engineer (a little self-deprecating humor is good for the soul), so be gentle.

EDIT:

I also realize that the utility of the `dict`, in its current form, would need to be expanded a bit to offer all the bells/whistles of `list`. Some things missing currently include an `insert` method, or a `reverse` method, and ***slicing*** (the big gaping hole in functionality, of course). But these are things that it would make sense to add to a full-fledged ordered `dict` object.

Alternatively, perhaps it would be useful to add a `dlist`, or `ldict`, to the `collections` module- a `dict` that only accepts `int` keys, and with all the missing functionality from `list`. More memory use, but faster modifications.

Comment: The dictionary does impose limitations on its keys, they must be hashable.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Indexes are `int`s, and therefore hashable.

Comment: Is this part of the language specification or a private internal implementation  detail of CPython? IOW, is it guaranteed by the specification to work on IronPython, Jython, PyPy, Pyston, Pynie, and any and all possible future implementation?

Comment: But lists and arrays don't store their indices. They're both more memory efficient and faster at lookups than the dicts are.

Comment: @JörgWMittag currently implementation detail but *it seems* like that will change in the future.

Comment: I don't see any slice support on the horizon, neither insertion at an arbitrary position nor popleft()....

Comment: Even if the internal implementation changes, the public interface shouldn't. `list.append` is much more cumbersome to replicate using a `dict`.

Comment: By "everything", do you include `set` and `tuple` in that…?

Comment: @deceze What is cumbersome about doing `my_dict[new_entry] = 'foo'`?

Comment: @Ev. Figuring out the value of `new_entry`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It is not currently required, but it probably soon will be.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Or perhaps the intention is `[1, 2, [3]]` as `{0:1, 1:2, 2:{0:3}}`?

Comment: Mathematical computations considering vectors make more sense as lists than dictionaries. Imagine trying to take the transpose of a dictionary. :/

Comment: In the end a dictionary is a hash table, and sometimes a hash table just isn't the right tool.

Comment: @deceze For a long while, `set` didn't exist and people just used `dict` keys for `set`s.

Comment: @Rick And thank god we have moved past that and now have a proper `set` type which we can use with arbitrary objects which can themselves define their unique id via a defined interface, and which make set operations easy and fast.

Comment: @deceze long live (unordered) `set`s!

Answer (score 5):

For starters, there are memory considerations:

```
l = [ i for i in range(100000) ]
d = { i:i for i in range(100000) }
print("List: {}, Dict: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(l), sys.getsizeof(d)))
```

outputs: `List: 824464, Dict: 6291552`…

Comment: This is a huge reason to not replace lists with dictionaries; what if you're not interested in storing keys for the values?

Comment: @Tom the indexes ARE the keys. But yes, 7.5x the size is an issue in many cases. But memory consumption seems to be less and less critical for many problems.

Comment: I'd suggest reverting `l` and `d` in print, since you haven't named them `list` and `dictionary` it can confuse people since the list is defined second

Comment: @RickTeachey I suppose you could hack dictionaries to do this, but what I meant was you can easily create a list without explicitly linking each item to a key, whereas you must specify what key an item has when creating a dictionary.

Comment: @TomWyllie True enough. I agree the memory consumption seems a good enough reason on its own to preserve `list`s as currently implemented. Still seems to be an open question, though, if one is simply not concerned about memory consumption (very often the case), whether a ordered `dict` with some added utility might be a nice thing to have.

Comment: @RickTeachey If we started using dicts for the only reason that they're ordered, then back portability will become a serious issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I also realize that the utility of the `dict`, in its current form, would need to be expanded a bit to offer all the bells/whistles of `list`.

Let's take one of those whistles: `list.append`. If `dict` now sprouts an `append` method, how does that work exactly? It's fine when you're abusing a `dict` as a `list`:

```
lst = {}
lst.append('foo')
lst.append('bar')
```

But what now?

```
lst = {'foo': 'bar'}
lst.append('baz')
```

The expected result? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Arguably, PHP has these kinds of arrays:

```php
$lst = ['foo' => 'bar'];
$lst[] = 'baz';
// ['foo' => 'bar', 0 => 'baz']
```

And, quite frankly, mixing two types of keys is extremely cumbersome in practice with very little upside to it, since you cannot iterate an array and depend on its keys being numerical and in order.

So, even if the internal implementation should change so `list`s are `dict`s, the public interface shouldn't change. Lists are simply for very different use cases than key-value maps.

Ordered `dict`s are great for replacing `OrderedDict`s though.

Comment: not sure I am following.. If `list`s were `dict`s, `lst = {}; lst.append('foo'); lst.append('bar')` would result in `lst = {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar'}`, and not `lst = {'foo': 'bar'}`.. So doing then `lst.append('baz')` would not be an issue.. Or am I deeply confused?

Comment: Yes, if you start with an empty `dict` and exclusively use `append`, you get a number of numeric keys, fine. But since you *can* mix numeric keys and arbitrary keys, how do you resolve the situation when both of those clash together? Again, the result is a mix, which makes your "list" terribly unpredictable. PHP developers are dealing with this every day, and it does add overhead.

Comment: I agree with @Ev.Kounis (or I am equally confused), I guess the idea is that `list` would become a sub-class of `dict` where the keys were always fixed to the indexes?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Again, if the internal implementation switches to `dict`s, fine. But `list`s should still behave as lists and not allow mixed keys. No, as a developer I will not replace a `list` with a `dict` (what OP was asking) because *they behave differently*.

Comment: @Chris_Rands or maybe a special `dict` subtype that only accepts `int` keys and with all the missing `list` functionality added. Call it a `dictlist`, or `dlist`, or `ldict`? More memory use, faster lookup. Put it in the `collections` module?

Comment: @Rick `list` lookups are already pretty darn fast, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825147/476. Aren't you comparing apples to oranges here (old `dict` vs. new `dict` vs. `list`)?

Comment: Probably am. :) But I do know when doing a LOT of lookups, the `dict` is much faster. And currently, if what you want is slicing, appending, etc. coupled with the fastest lookup possible, there's no built-in option.

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing lookup with modification. For instance, pop and insert are actually expensive.

Comment: @YannVernier You're right- that's exactly what I was getting confused. Thanks.

Comment: @deceze I retract. I was thinking about inserting, etc.

Comment: On that note, [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is good to know about.

Comment: PEP 20, the Zen of Python (found by `import this`), states "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess." In this case, append would probably have to refuse to operate if we had non-integer keys. Put another way, if list were a subtype of dict, it would restrict the keys to integer. The next invariant of lists to be ported is that indices are contiguous integers starting from 0. Its mere existence means the structure to consider moving to for lists isn't dicts but ropes.

Comment: @Yann Yes, basically "new dicts" would be *greeeaaat* for lists… *iiiiif* you changed some fundamental parts about how they work. At which point… what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

When considering a change to a datatype in the library, such as `dict`, the comparisons are all against the previous version of that type. We see size improvements like 20-25% without huge speed loss, for instance.

That doesn't mean it improves on other data types. For instance, Python's `list` type is an array of object references in CS terms. It basically stores those references and how many they are, nothing more. There are downsides to this such as having to copy the entire array if it is moved when growing, which is something a linked list could avoid. But the array also allows trivial lookups by index; you just multiply the index by the element size, add it to the array pointer, and you're done. No searching is involved. Similarly, the last index is known because we have the number of entries. The indices themselves aren't stored at all. If we make some crude approximations such as keys, hashes and values all requiring the same size, and hash tables never being sparse, we see the dictionary takes three times the space of the list; 25% improvement on that still means 125% worse space efficiency for a list.

Dictionaries do store their keys. In CS term, they are maps, and classically implemented using hash tables. That's why keys need to be hashable; the hash is used as a shortcut so we don't need to compare the keys themselves, but can use the hashes for most checks. The upside to hash tables is they typically only need one lookup, but a downside is again that they need to be recalculated any time the table size changes. Trees make a different tradeoff here, allowing O(log(n)) lookups instead of O(1). The Python language itself requires that `dict` keys be usable for hash tables but doesn't guarantee that `dict` is implemented using them. Another tradeoff with hash tables is that the key order becomes dependent on the table size, which is why `dict` is unordered.

There do exist languages which eschew the difference, such as Lua's table type. It can operate as both dictionary and array (and with metatables, also as classes). Python has more distinct types, for instance `set` which is much like `dict` but drops the values, only having the keys, or `array` which only stores type information once, and can therefore store values instead of references, but only of one (numeric) type.

Comment: [Lua](https://lua.org/) tables were the first thing I thought of. [MISC](http://will.thimbleby.net/misc/) dictionaries and [PHP](https://php.net/) associative arrays are another example.